# Merge two lines into one within a configuration file

Tags: perl, shell, awk, sed, ksh

I have several AIX systems with a configuration file, let's call it **/etc/bar/config**.  The file may or may not have a line declaring values for **foo**.  An example would be:

```
foo = A_1,GROUP_1,USER_1,USER_2,USER_3
```

The **foo** line may or may not be the same on all systems.  Different systems may have different values and different a different number of values.  My task is to add "bare minimum" values in the **config** file on all systems.  The bare minimum line will look like this.

```
foo = A_1,USER_1,SYS_1,SYS_2
```

If the line does not exist, I must create it.  If the line does exist, I must merge the two lines.  Using my examples, the result would be this.  The order of the values does not matter.

```
foo = A_1,GROUP_1,USER_1,USER_3,USER_2,SYS_1,SYS_2
```

Obviously I want a script to do my work.  I have the standard *sh*, *ksh*, *awk*, *sed*, *grep*, *perl*, *cut*, etc.  Since this is AIX, I do not have access to the GNU versions of these utilities.

Originally, I had a script with these commands to replace the entire **foo** line.

```
cp /etc/bar/config /etc/bar/config.$$
sed "s/foo = .*/foo = A_1,USER_1,SYS_1,SYS_2/" /etc/bar/config.$$ > /etc/bar/config
```

But this simply replaces the line.  It does take into consideration any pre-existing configuration, including a line that's missing.  And I'm doing other configuration modifications in the script, such as adding completely unique lines to other files and restarting a process, so I'd *perfer* this be some type of shell-based code snippet I can add to my change script.  I am open to other options, especially if the solution is simpler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Untested bash, etc.

```
config=/etc/bar/config
default=A_1,USER_1,SYS_1,SYS_2
pattern='^foo[[:blank:]]*=[[:blank:]]*'   # shared with grep and sed
if current=$( grep "$pattern" "$config" | sed "s/$pattern//" )
then 
    new=$( echo "$current,$default" | tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq | paste -sd, )
    sed "s/$pattern.*/foo = $new/" "$config" > "$config.$$.tmp" &&
        mv "$config.$$.tmp" "$config"
else
    echo "foo = $default" >> "$config"
fi
```

A vanilla perl solution:

```
perl -i -lpe '
    BEGIN {%foo = map {$_ => 1} qw/A_1 USER_1 SYS_1 SYS_2/}
    if (s/^foo\s*=\s*//) {
        $found=1; 
        $foo{$_}=1 for split /,/; 
        $_ = "foo = " . join(",", keys %foo);
    }
    END {print "foo = " . join(",", keys %foo) unless $found}
' /etc/bar/config
```

Comment: OP said "Since this is AIX, I do not have access to the GNU versions of these utilities."

Comment: I can sometimes work around GNU things like "sed -i".  man(1) is still my friend on what works and what doesn't.

Comment: I think I've removed the GNUiness from the first one. Still largely untested

Comment: Both examples rely on there being exactly one space either side of the `=`

Comment: My original config file does have exactly one space on either side of the `=`.  I'd like to preserve that.

Comment: That whole use of tr to sort/uniq the string is **very cool**!

Comment: I'm accepting this one.  It's shell code.  (No offense meant to Perl users.  Shell is my preference.)  The `sort | uniq | paste -sd,` is shorter, though somewhat less clear, than `sort | uniq | tr '\n' ',' | sed s'/.$//'`

Comment: Dang, `paste -sd,` did not work on all my AIX systems.  I used `tr` to put the commas back.

Answer (score 1):

Some dirty bash/sed:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
input_file="some_filename"
v=$(grep -n '^foo *=' "$input_file")
lineno=$(cut -d: -f1 <<< "${v}0:")
base="A_1,USER_1,SYS_1,SYS_2,"
if [[ "$lineno" == 0 ]]; then
    echo "foo = A_1,USER_1,SYS_1,SYS_2" >> "$input_file"
else 
    all=$(sed -n ${lineno}'s/^foo *= */'"$base"'/p' "$input_file" | \
        tr ',' '\n' | sort | uniq | tr '\n' ',' | \
        sed -e 's/^/foo = /' -e 's/, *$//' -e 's/   */ /g' <<< "$all") 
    sed -i "${lineno}"'s/.*/'"$all"'/' "$input_file"
fi
```

Comment: I may have BASH available.  It looks like this will work with KORN, though.  If I could upvote you for `lineno=$(cut -d: -f1 <<< "${v}0:")`, I would.  I didn't know you could do that with those.

Comment: Also, that whole use of tr to sort/uniq the string is **very cool**!

Answer (score 0):

This Perl code will do as you ask. It expects the path to the file to be modified as a parameter on the command line.

Note that it reads the entire input file into the array `@config` and then overwrites the same file with the modified data.

It works by building a hash `%values` from a combination of the items already present in the `foo =` line and the list of defaults items in `@defaults`. The combination is sorted in alphabetical order and joined eith a comma

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my @defaults = qw/ A_1 USER_1 SYS_1 SYS_2 /;

my ($file) = @ARGV;
my @config = <>;

open my $out_fh, '>', $file or die $!;
select $out_fh;

for ( @config ) {
  if ( my ($pfx, $vals) = /^(foo \s* = \s* ) (.+) /x ) {
    my %values;
    ++$values{$_} for $vals =~ /[^,\s]+/g;
    ++$values{$_} for @defaults;
    print $pfx, join(',', sort keys %values), "\n";
  }
  else {
    print;
  }
}

close $out_fh;
```

**output**

```
foo = A_1,GROUP_1,SYS_1,SYS_2,USER_1,USER_2,USER_3
```

Comment: You need to add the `foo` line if it's not found in the file.

Comment: Or at least determine if `foo` is not there.  I will probably have to _other stuff not mentioned in the question_ to insert it in the correct location.

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't provide sample input and expected output I couldn't test this but this is the right approach:

```
awk '
/foo = / { old = ","$3; next }
{ print }
END {
    split("A_1,USER_1,SYS_1,SYS_2"old,all,/,/)
    for (i in all)
        if (!seen[all[i]]++)
            new = (new ? new "," : "") all[i]
    print "foo =", new
}
' /etc/bar/config > tmp && mv tmp /etc/bar/config
```